# Add self-signed certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, security, certificate

I would like to access my Synology NAS via HTTPS, but don't have the money to buy a certificate. I've read that you can generate your own and manually trust it. So after following the step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate), I generated a crt file of my own CA, then AirDropped it to my iPhone. Then I manually trusted the profile.

However, when I access my Synology NAS in Safari, the connection still shows up as "insecure". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the Synology that has to have the certificate, not just your phone.

Try following https://jeangalea.com/setup-ssl-synology-nas/

Comment: I did import that certificate into my Synology NAS and set it as default, and when I trust the CA certificate in my MacBooks it all worked. It's just my iPhone that didn't work.